# Have Table Value Function return NULLS if no record exists

Tags: sql-server, join, user-defined-functions, cross-apply

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 to retrieve records which I perform multiple `CROSS APPLY`'s to various table valued functions to expand on values from the original table.

In the event that the TVF does not return results, I still want to see the contact but with NULL values in the columns that the TVF would have returned had it generated a result.

Is there a way to have a table valued function return a row of NULL values rather than just 'no records exist'?  I imagine there's some JOIN magic I need to apply but I'm not getting anywhere.

I've resorted to a UNION clause in the TVF that returns NULL for each column but this will give me duplicates if the TVF returns a match (One result WITH the matching values and one with the NULLs)

Answer (score 0):

Well, answered my own question here...  Didn't think to try an OUTER APPLY instead of a CROSS APPLY.  That did the trick.